# Run PERCENT_RANK() and save result to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, create-table

I have a table that looks something like this

```
instID    xx     yy    zz
   2       2     9     6
   3      11     5     9
   4      13     3     14
```

I want to run a `PERCENT_RANK()` query for the fields xx,yy,zz and then save them to a table with the same instID numbers.

Right now I run a `Percent_Rank` query for each of them, but I can't either figure out how to save data I get from the query, and/or if its possible to do the ranking for each of them separately but in the same query?

Here is the simple code I'm running now

```
select 
xx,
yy,
zz,
ROUND(
    PERCENT_RANK() OVER (
        ORDER BY xx desc
    ) 

,2) percentile_rank
FROM table;
```

Comment: My guess is, come up with a query that shows the data you want, then stick that into a CTE, and use the results of that CTE to insert into a new table, or update an existing table.

Comment: Well you can repeat the `percent_rank` for each of your 3 columns? And then as pmbAustin says, use a CTE to update/insert into a table. Its not clear where you are trying to save it.

Answer (score 2):

If I follow you correctly, you can use the `select ... into` syntax, and percent rank each column:

```
select xx, yy, zz,
    percent_rank() over(order by xx) xx_pct_rn,
    percent_rank() over(order by yy) yy_pct_rn,
    percent_rank() over(order by zz) zz_pct_rn
into newtable
from mytable
```

This creates a new table, called `newtable`, that contains as many rows as the original table, with three additional columns which store the percent rank of the three original columns.

Comment: yeah this one works great, but is it possible to add the calculations to an existing table with the percentile ranks as well?

Comment: i mean so i dont create a neew table everytime i run the code